# Bootstrap 3 new grid system and col-lg

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying migrate from bootstrap 2 to 3 but i have problem with new grid system in which is `col-lg-*` instead `span*`

Im lame in english so i show my problem on examples:

Base bootstrap 2 template: 
http://bootply.com/71498

And bootstrap 3, the same template but in which i used `col-lg-*` instead `span*`

http://bootply.com/71499

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the tags changed. Like "thumbnail" is now "img-thumbnail" and nested rows should usually stack up to 12 columns total.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    </header>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        Column 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Friend explained me how it works now, thanks for thumbnail tip.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    </header>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```